# How can view jquery appended data using browsers view page source option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, view-source

Iam appending some data to a table in my php page. Data is shown in web page. That's ok. Then I opened the view page source in my web browser. But I didn't see that data in page source. Is there any method to show that data in page source?
This is my code

```
for (var i in Newdata) {
    $('.dataTables_empty').hide();
    var str = "<tr id='row" + Newdata[i].VehicleTypeID + "'>" +
              "<td><p id='" + Newdata[i].VehicleTypeID + "'>" + Newdata[i].VehicleTypeName + "</p></td>" +
              "<td><a href='#' class='datatable' id='edit' valuefield='" + Newdata[i].VehicleTypeID + "' action='edit' fieldname='VehicleTypeName' modal-name='Type-Modal'><button class='icon-edit'>Edit</button></a></td>" +
              "<td><a href='#' class='datatable' id='delete' valuefield='" + Newdata[i].VehicleTypeID + "' action='delete'><button class='icon-delete'>Delete</button></a></td>" +
             "</tr>";
   var $row = $(str).appendTo("#BrandTypeTable tbody");
  }
```

Comment: I have to get it in html, so that datatable will work properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`View Page Source` shows the code as it appears in the HTML source file<sup>1</sup>. You can use the [page inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector) in the developer tools (accessible via <kbd>F12</kbd> in most browsers) to see the "live" DOM tree.

If you need to access the current page HTML within your Javascript code, you can use `document.body.innerHTML` or similar.

---

<sup>1: More accurately, it shows "what was initially received from the server", since the HTML may have been generated by PHP, Rails, or similar.</sup>